# How is global warming distributed with respect to altitude?

Tags: atmospheric-science, climate-science, exoplanets

Lets assume a sea level temperature increase 2c/3c. Then, what is the temperature increase at 10 km altitude? Temperature increase at 30 km altitude? Temperature increase at 70 km altitude? And Temperature increase at 500 m below sea level? etc. etc. Please give full description of global temp increase with special regard to C02 as night time insulator and water as night time heat source. Structure of CO2 molecule. How does it do it?

1. Is it true that increases in CO2 slow down the atmosphere's cooling rate per kilometre of altitude by trapping progressively larger amounts of infra-red energy within the body of the atmosphere?
2. Is it true that the temperature increase resulting from CO2 emissions ultimately occurs at the top of the atmosphere, which is close to space and heat loss?

Comment: Yes, simple physics tells you that increasing levels of CO2 is a problem for the planet. And, the temperature increase can be and is observed right down here on the surface of the earth, as well as in the oceans.

Comment: The oceans are indeed huge thermal reservoirs.  But they are not magic: if you pour energy into the ocean it will warm.  So the answer to your question (3) is clearly no: I'm not sure why you would think otherwise.

Comment: @JonCuster, it's no longer "simple physics" when so many variables are involved in the problem.  Considering only the fact that CO2 absorbs infrared radiation misses the fact that the CO2 absorption band is already saturated, so adding more CO2 has much less effect than one would think.  In addition, if warming causes more water vapor in the atmosphere, there will be effects on atmospheric convection, and albedo from cloud cover and possibly more snow fall.

Comment: @tfb If increasing amounts of CO2 trap more and more infra red at the surface and lower atmosphere does it follow that the upper atmosphere is getting progressively cooler?

Comment: No.  That radiation previously escaped to space.

Comment: @DavidWhite Though there *are* further effects to consider. For example, increasing CO2 concentrations in the atmosphere raises the surface of last scattering, which tends to increase the average temperature at sea level. [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hUFOuoD3aHw]

Comment: @tfb, keep in mind that there is a continuous radiation flux escaping to space, so the word "previously" may not apply.

Comment: @DavidWhite: By 'previously' I meant 'compared to the state with a lower CO2 concentration in the atmosphere': the amount of heat in the atmosphere is obviously not a conserved quantity so if part of it becomes warmer as a result of a greenhouse effect another part does not have to cool!

Comment: Could a laboratory test prove a CO2 effect? 1. Build large greenhouse, like an aircraft hangar, on plain open area. Water free conditions in Atacama desert? 2. Measure temperatures in sealed space at night-time low point to establish insulating effect of sealed structure. Cold clear night. Compare with outside ground temperatures. 3. Change gas in greenhouse to 100% CO2 at standard pressure. 4. Measure temperatures again to compare with outside ground temperatures. Observe CO2 effect caused by change gases in greenhouse.

Temp up  at top or base of greenhouse? See Question 1 at start.

Comment: @CO2, we already know that there IS a CO2 effect.  The big question right now is how big of an effect human generated CO2 is having.  Current data implies that the effect is much smaller than the alarmists are telling everyone.

Comment: And the question? Is an artificial laboratory experiment possible? e.g mixing water and CO2? Some people say that CO2 without water is no effective at increasing temp. etc. Re-produce everything under laboratory conditions?

Comment: The idea in the original post that the water cannot get hotter is based on night time energy transfer from ocean to cold atmosphere. During the day energy accumulates in water; then released at night. Water is the heat source, like battery/night storage radiator. Scattering of infra red by CO2  delays energy transfer to space. So cooling per kilometre of altitude slows. Melting glaciers but  minimal effect at beach??

Comment: @CO2: sea surface temperatures are empirically rising: we can measure them, and we do measure them, and they're rising.  See, for instance [this NASA page](https://data.giss.nasa.gov/gistemp/).

Comment: OK. The question asks whether the ocean is a night time heater (heat source) that releases energy  at night into a cold object (air). It is suggested that the cold side of the object (the top of the atmosphere) is the place where all or most heating occurs. It is suggested that the CO2 effect changes the cooling rate per km of altitude. Compare: one shuts a window in bedroom. The cold side of the room warms. The side of the room close to  the heater stays at a fixed temperature.

Comment: OK. Lets assume sea level temp increase 2c/3c. Then, what is Temp increase at 10 km altitude? Temp increase at 30 km altitude? Temp increase at 70 km altitude? And Temp increase at 500 m below sea level? etc. etc. Please give full description of global temp increase with special regard to C02 as night time insulator and water as night time heat source. Structure of CO2 molecule. How does it do it?

Answer (score 4):

Without any CO$_2$ in the atmosphere the earth would be a very cold place, about 40 or 50 centrigrades colder than now. Trace molecules in the atmosphere radiate about as much energy to the surface as the sun.

It is sometimes argued that the greenhouse effect is saturated. And it is true that the effect of doubling the CO$_2$ content is "small": it gives an increase of the radiation with just 4 % or so. And to radiate that away, the surface temperature would just increase by $1$ % (Stefan-Boltzmann $T^4$ law).

But $1$ % of 300 K means an increase of 3 centigrades, which is catastrophic.

The top of the troposphere remains at the same temperature, 260 kelvin or so, or marginally cooler. The earth radiates as much as it absorbs from the sun. (Or actually slightly less until steady state is reached.) The only way this would change if when the albedo of the earth would change.

The sea is becoming warmer. At least the top layers. More moisture in the atmosphere, more energy in hurricanes.

(Very approximate numbers here.)

Comment: The infrared absorption band for CO2 is more-or-less saturated, meaning that adding more CO2 has a very small effect.  As far as more moisture in the atmosphere leading to more severe hurricanes, I'm not so sure about that.  An energy balance over the ocean that "bleeds" excess energy to outer space via convection and radiation, but leaves the  surface temperature warmer than a "base case" whereby CO2 was at a lower level, would be required to answer this question.

Comment: @DavidWhite It is undeniable that hurricanes are powered by warm seas. They can be analyzed as heat engines, and are said to approach Carnot efficiency in the conversion of heat to mechanical energy as wind. And a higher moisture content will give more rain.

Comment: Pieter, I realize that more moisture content means more rain.  However, higher ocean surface temperature is not necessarily higher heat transfer.  It's easy to make a hidden erroneous assumption for problems like this, and a heat balance is required to verify this type of hidden assumption.  In other words, if a higher ocean surface temperature leads to more intense hurricanes, why doesn't this increased intensity lead to enough temperature change to bring the ocean temperature back to its "lower CO2" equilibrium temperature?

Comment: I think PBS had a good TV special, they mentioned the earth's core and crust needs to radiate heat outwards to space thru the atmosphere, the more CO2 the more insulating and therefore an atmospheric temperature increase. The 2 main heat sources are the sun and the core!

Comment: @DavidWhite _why doesn't this increased intensity lead to enough temperature change to bring the ocean temperature back to its "lower CO2" equilibrium temperature?_ Obviously, energy conservation dictates that the hurricane must carry away thermal energy from the ocean. But why do you think this should lead to the ocean maintaining some arbitrary temperature? It will simply shift to a new equilibrium point.

Comment: @DavidWhite: it's rather fortunate for us that not all the energy in raised SSTs is carried away by hurricanes!

Comment: @PhysicsDave: the energy from the core is tiny: it's something like $0.1\,\mathrm{W/m^2}$ which is utterly negligible compared to solar radiation.  It is more than human energy generation however!

Comment: @tfb, I didn't mean to imply that all of the energy in SST's was carried away by hurricanes.  Is there enough energy carried away to drop SST's back to what they were before a given CO2 rise?  I doubt it, and because of that, I am not ready to automatically conclude that hurricanes would get much stronger when SST's are warmer ... a heat balance should be done to confirm this.  And if you're wondering, I DO have experience with a very large mathematical model, which occasionally produced results that were counter-intuitive.

Comment: @DavidWhite This does not depend only on models. Empirically, hurricanes require a sea surface temperature of at least 26 C to develop and grow. If larger areas would be over this threshold for a longer time, one might also expect a longer hurricane season, with more hurricanes, or hurricanes that are larger in size.

Comment: @Pieter, I agree.  I expect the same thing that you do.  However, my expectations have been wrong before, and it's best to actually collect real world data to verify expectations and hidden assumptions.

Comment: @DavidWhite: That's not what I meant: you can do Fermi estimation on this.  Assuming a mixing depth of 20m (which I think is conservative) then I get about $3\times 10^{22}\,\mathrm{J}$ to heat the mixed layer of the oceans by a degree.  The power in a hurricane (most of which is rainfall) [seems to be](http://www.aoml.noaa.gov/hrd/tcfaq/D7.html) $6\times 10^{14}\,\mathrm{W}$ so this is about 18 months of hurricane.  That's actually not as bad as I thought, but it's bad.

Comment: @Pieter, in reading your posting, I have doubts that a 3 deg C increase in temperature would be "catastrophic".  The proxy temperature record of the earth clearly indicates that this temperature has been experienced before.  In addition, I have a small math model for this problem that implies that a 3 deg C rise requires 630 ppm CO2.  From a pre-industrial level of 280 ppm to the current 400 ppm, the difference is 120 ppm.  It would take another rise of 230 ppm CO2 to get to the 3 deg C.  That would require burning a LOT more fossil fuel.

Comment: @David I wrote that my numbers were approximate. But 3 degrees is  unprecedented in human history; no Londoners saw the hippos in the Thames. There would be regional hot spots. There would likely occur deadly heatwaves in which millions would die in cities like Lucknow or Shanghai.